# OLS regression with artificial data

Tags: data-transformation, least-squares

I want to estimate the following relationship:

$Y=c\cdot ln\frac{X_1}{X_1-X_2}$

where $Y$ is the dependent and $X_1$, $X_2$ independent variables. However, I don't have explicit data for $Y$, so I have constructed my own series based on the following relationship, $Y=aX_2$, which is valid.

Also, I define $Z$ as $ln\frac{X_1}{X_1-X_2}$ and estimate the following expression using OLS:

$Y=cZ$

The results are satisfying, i.e., parameter $c$ has the expected magnitude and sign, it is statistical significant, and both $R^2$ and $\bar{R}^2 $ are above 80%. However, I am afraid that what I do is wrong because of $X_2$ presence in both $Y$ and $Z$. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well you've just regressed $X_2$ on a nonlinear function of $X_1$ and $X_2$. What's the issue?